# changing Location in the http response

Tags: regex, http, http-headers, http-status-code-301, haproxy

While accessing https://myexample.com/adminui/ server send 303 and I am getting response in the browser as below

```
http://uaa.devtest3.io/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=admin_ui_client&redirect_uri=https://admin.devtest3.io/login
```

I want it to change it

```
http://myexample.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=admin_ui_client&redirect_uri=https://myexample.com/adminui/login
```

I tried following entry in haproxy.config file,but this is not working.

```
resirep ^Location:\ http://uaa.devtest3.io/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=admin_ui_client&redirect_uri=https://admin.devtest3.io/login   Location:\ http://myexample.com/uaa/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=admin_ui_client&redirect_uri=https://myexample.com/adminui/login
```

**UPDATED**
I need further help to change

```
https://uaa.devtest3.io/login;jsessionid=4A0ADA8DDB7CD09C2B50F4A41945BBDB to https://myexample.com/uaa/login;jsessionid=4A0ADA8DDB7CD09C2B50F4A41945BBDB
```

I tried this

```
rspirep ^Location:\ (https?://uaa.devtest3.io;jsessionid=([0-9A-Z](.*) )Location:\ myexample.com \3 if hdr_location
```

This is not working.I feel regex i am using is wrong.I am not verse in this regexe.
Please guide me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `resirep` command does not appear to exist as far as I can tell. I think the command you need is `rspirep`. Second, if you are using HAProxy version 1.5 or below you need to escape `/`, `&` and `?` as well as the spaces.

Resulting configuration:

```
rspirep ^Location:\ http:\/\/uaa.devtest3.io\/oauth\/authorize\?response_type=code\&client_id=admin_ui_client\&redirect_uri=https:\/\/admin.devtest3.io\/login   Location:\ http:\/\/myexample.com\/uaa\/oauth\/authorize\?response_type=code\&client_id=admin_ui_client\&redirect_uri=https:\/\/myexample.com\/adminui\/login
```

Hope that helps.

**Update *Fixed**

```
rspirep ^Location:\ https:\/\/uaa.devtest3.io\/login;jsessionid=([0-9A-Z]*)   Location:\ https:\/\/myexample.com\/uaa\/login;jsessionid=\1
```

`([0-9A-Z]*)` - matches and captures a string of any length that contains capital letters and numbers.

`\1` - place the first captured string here

*tested in HAProxy 1.5.15.

Comment: I am trying  this and let you know

Comment: Its working fine.I nee to chnage one more https://uaa.devtest3.io/login;jsessionid=4A0ADA8DDB7CD09C2B50F4A41945BBDB to https://myexample.com/uaa/login;jsessionid=4A0ADA8DDB7CD09C2B50F4A41945BBDB to

Comment: jsessionid=4A0ADA8DDB7CD09C2B50F4A41945BBDB will be dynamic,so some regex need to done